# Windows Phone 8 - Scheduled Agent LaunchForTest ticks only one time

Tags: windows-phone-8, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to update my lockscreen image using a scheduled agent.
I've been running tests in debug using:

```
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(TaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I've put a break point in my OnInvoke function and on NotifyComplete() in order to check that everything is working correctly.

It seems that the OnInvoke function is called only one time:
I've been able to update my lockscreen after 10 seconds, I've checked that my code was running to NotifyComplete(). But it will never tick again, whereas it should be ticking every 10 seconds.
Is it a normal behaviour ? How can I actually verify that the Periodic task is beeing called several times ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in your ScheduledAgent.cs as well:

```
 protected override async void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
     // If debugging is enabled, launch the agent again in one minute.
#if DEBUG_AGENT
      ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but generally speaking, does it mean this LaunchForTest instruction is supposed to run ONLY ONE TIME ?

Comment: Yes each time the code is called it is launched once hence why you must set it to launch again after each run.

Comment: Okay. So now I understand better. Thanks. So what should I check next if it's running fine in debug but never updates in release once I remove the LaunchForTest instruction ?

Comment: Perhaps your background task takes too long time to execute? Think max seconds are 25. Or perhaps you are running out of memory? Could be a lot of reasons, add some logging or something like that.